# Model Selection - 6 month forecast given the past 25 months

Tags: time-series, projection

As the title states, the problem at hand is asking me to predict the next 6 months values when given the past 25 months. In my opinion, the training data will be quite thin so traditional time series methods (ARIMA) may not work (could be completely wrong, please validate).

What would be the best way to approach this and why?

EDIT:

I also want to mention that I'm not just dealing with a time stamp and a value. I will have many other features as well.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the forecast package in R, specifically the auto.arima function:

[Forecast](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf)

You can pass other regressors into the fitting process using the xreg parameter.